# Python ValueError: A given column is not a column of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to create a predictive maintenance model but I encountered an error. How can I resolve it?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix

from IPython.display import display

## Data importation
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\berin\OneDrive\Bureau\Projet ML Predictive Maintenance\predictive_maintenance.csv')
display(data.head(5))
display(data.isna().sum()) ## Look if there is missing data
display(data.info())

# categorical = ["Product ID","Type","Failure_type"]
# numeric = ["Air temperature [K]", "Process temperature [K]", "Rotational speed [rpm]", "Torque [Nm]", "Tool wear [min]"]

transformer = make_column_transformer(
    (MinMaxScaler(), "Air temperature [K]"),
    (MinMaxScaler(), "Process temperature [K]"),
    (MinMaxScaler(), "Rotational speed [rpm]"),
    (MinMaxScaler(), "Torque [Nm]"),
    (MinMaxScaler(), "Tool wear [min]"),
    (OneHotEncoder(), "Product ID"),
    (OneHotEncoder(), "Type"),
    (OneHotEncoder(), "Failure_type"),
    remainder='drop' #Permet d'enlever UDI qui est inutile
)


x = data.drop('Failure_type', axis=1)
y = data['Failure_type']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
model = make_pipeline(transformer, RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42))
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\berin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3791, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "index.pyx", line 152, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "index.pyx", line 181, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7080, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7088, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Failure_type'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\berin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 447, in _get_column_indices
    col_idx = all_columns.get_loc(col)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\berin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3798, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Failure_type'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\berin\OneDrive\Bureau\Projet ML Predictive Maintenance\main.py", line 40, in <module>
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\berin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 1152, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\berin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 423, in fit
    Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\berin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 377, in _fit
    X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\berin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\joblib\memory.py", line 353, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\berin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 957, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\berin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_set_output.py", line 157, in wrapped
    data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\berin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 1152, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\berin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py", line 751, in fit_transform
    self._validate_column_callables(X)
  File "C:\Users\berin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py", line 459, in _validate_column_callables       
    transformer_to_input_indices[name] = _get_c^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\berin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 455, in _get_column_indices

    raise ValueError("A given column is not a column of the dataframe") from e
ValueError: A given column is not a column of the dataframe
```

I tried all the solutions proposed by other topics but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is from the `(OneHotEncoder(), "Failure_type")` in the `make_column_transformer` preprocessor which is applied to the input features X and not your target variable. The column 'Failure_type' is not present in your data frame when you try to fit the model because,  in your code, you drop the "Failure_type" column before splitting the data into training and testing sets. You can try to modify your `transformer` to remove the target column "Failure_type"